# How to access different domain data using Java script

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

Here is the issue. Suppose there is a **DOMAIN A** which is going to be the server containing a **PHP Script** file. The data from Domain A is to be accessed by a **Client at DOMAIN B**.

I know it cannot be accessed directly using JavaScript. So what I did is, in Domain A I created a a JavaScript file as front-end for the PHP Script which AJAXes the PHP and returns the data. But unfortunately it din't work

I came across an example having PHP as a Middle Man in the client side. But I donot want to keep any server side PHP code as a middle man in the client side. I just want to give out the Javascript to the client domain.

[How to get data with JavaScript from another server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578095/how-to-get-data-with-javascript-from-another-server)

**DOMAIN A**

PHP - data.php

```
<?php echo "Server returns data"; ?>
```

JS - ***example.js***

Does the Ajax to the PHP

```
function getData()
{
   //assume ajax is done for data.php and data is retrieved, now return the data
   return ajaxed_data;
}
```

**Domain B**

JS

Client includes the **example.js** file from **Domain A** in his HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.DomainA.com/example.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     alert(getData());
</script>
```

I hope I have made myself understandable ! Can this be established ? Its something like Google friend connect, what I mean is, just provide JavaScript to the client and thats it. Every thing carried out in server side

Thankx for providing this forum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [JSONP](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/). jQuery has a [good support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for it.

DOMAIN A - data.php:

```
<?php
    $data = '{ "data" : "Server returns data" }';
    echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $data . ');';
?>
```

DOMAIN B - client:

```
$.getJSON('http://domainA.com/data.php?jsoncallback=?', function(json) {
    alert(json.data);
});
```

Comment: Thanx for the solution, but it seems that it is not working across cross domains. If the server and client are in the same domain, its working, else no.

Comment: Could you define *not working*? The jQuery page I've linked to has a proof of concept example with pictures from Flickr showing cross domain ajax with JSONP. Can you show your code so far? Is a request sent to your php page? What does FireBug console show? I've just realized that I made a small typo in my post by using the `message` property in the js callback instead of `data`. I've fixed my post accordingly.

Comment: The problem remains the same i think ! Javascript can't access the server in cross domain directly. It needs an intermediate. I Used ajax from jQuery. JSON also giving the same response. null data is being retrieved.

Comment: thanx.. Its working now. I guess it was just the typo that caused the problem. Thanx a lot