# Retrieving data from MySQL with html/javaScript on one domain and the PHP file on the other

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I need to retrieve data from a MySQL database, and have it work one way for all types of servers. For example it should work on a server that runs no server side language, it should also work on LAMP, and IIS.

I was thinking about using ajax and xmlhttprequest, but learned of the cross domain limitation. I also tried to just include the PHP in a  tag, but it comes back with a syntax error in the HTML code created by the PHP file, even though it looks correct.

Does anyone know how to fix either of these issues, or have a different way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the cross-domain ajax, the result should be straight JavaScript code, and should not contain any HTML whatsoever. [This page has a description of the technique for cross-domain ajax](http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com/).

See Also: [How to access different domain data using Java script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616985/how-to-access-different-domain-data-using-java-script)

Comment: I've gone with the 2nd link on using jSON, but I'm still running into similar errors. What I'm trying to do is pull text and a url from a database and write <a> tags with the results. I'm basically creating the string in PHP and then echoing that out, but it says Error: missing ; before statement, and idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: here's the code...

$categories="<a href=" . '"' . "?catID=" . $row['catID'] . '"' . ">" . $row['CatName'] . "</a><br>";
     echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $categories . ');';