# How to get HTML code source from another site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-parsing

How do I get the HTML code of another site it wants cookies to be enabled?
I just need to **parse** this page `www.fx-trend.com/pamm/rating/`

I'm using javascript jquery (jQMobile) and sometimes PHP.(I prefer to use js)

**here is a sample with PHP:**

```
<?php
$url = 'url';
$html = file_get_html($url);
//$html = file_get_contents($url);
echo $html;
?>
```

**here is a sample with js:**
[How to get data with JavaScript from another server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578095/how-to-get-data-with-javascript-from-another-server)

OR

```
$(this).load(url);
alert($(this)); //returns object Object
```

**server answer:**

> Cookies must be enabled in your browser! Try to clear all cookies, if
>   cookies are enabled.

code samples are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Curl and enable cookies. The code sample below is snagged from [this page](http://coderscult.com/php/php-curl/2008/05/20/php-curl-cookies-example/).

```
<?php
/* STEP 1. let’s create a cookie file */
$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");

/* STEP 2. visit the homepage to set the cookie properly */
$ch = curl_init ("url");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$output = curl_exec ($ch);

var_dump($output);
```

Edit: You might have to fake a browser by changing the default user agent header.