# Loading external .js (github) libraries in in codepen

Tags: html, github, inject, codepen

Newbie question from a UX designer been trying to get this working for 2 days now.

I am trying to test out matthew dove's inject script in codepen
https://github.com/Matthew-Dove/Inject

I have copied the raw github file using jsdelivr into the Pen settings. When I click on the eye icon I can see the .js file.

[image: settings picture]

I have copied the example code provided by Matthew  into the html panel.

[image]

But as you can see in the image above the website does not get injected. 
My codepen is https://codepen.io/lisatw/pen/oNXxgMR

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="initial-scale=1,width=device-width" name="viewport">
<title>Inject</title>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Below this heading the world's first website will be injected</h4>

<div data-inject-src="http://info.cern.ch/" style="height: 175px;"> </div>

<h4>Above this heading the world's first website will be injected</h4>


</body>
</html>
```

I have tried with and without the call to the .js library

```
<script src="./inject.js"></script>
```

Any help mightly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a script on CodePen by URL, this URL will be injected as is before `</body>`. There is no need to explicitly adding script like this:

```js
<script src="./inject.js"></script>
```

Because right after that, CodePen automatically adds another script:

```js
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Matthew-Dove/Inject@master/src/inject.js"></script>
```

But the code doesn't work for another reason. This issue applies even to Matthew's https://rawgit.com/Matthew-Dove/Inject/master/src/example.html example, yahoo APIs (https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql) under the hood no longer available. https://twitter.com/ydn/status/1079785891558653952

Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Oh you star... at least I can stop thinking that I am being incredibly stupid!

Comment: Checked out alternatives from the original repository and they don't work either. I will try to write another alternative script, I hope this time it works. But I don't know another service like this though.

Comment: Yes I tried them too. 
I did find this on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54046823/yql-query-service-replacement-now-that-yahoo-shut-it-down

Comment: Also the import content alternative github.com/AndersDJohnson/html-imports-content Has this caniuse.com/#feat=imports -  it says "Deprecated method of including and reusing HTML documents in other HTML documents. Superseded by ES modules"

Comment: It turned out that is no easy way to make a request to another server. That's why they used a proxy server to bypass CORS policy, which browser using a lot for security reasons. Some servers in response send Access-Control-Allow-Origin header (which helps) and some don't (e.g. old maybe).
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-doesn-t-postman-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on

Comment: There are two options, you can simply use an iframe to display the site without any control over it. Or you need to use your own server to make a request to resource and then send it back to your site as HTML. Third-party proxy servers are unreliable and can be disabled at any time (like yahoo APIs).

Comment: I guessed it was because of security issues with cross site scripting attack issues being such an issue these days. An iframe won't work I don't think because I do want to alter the styling of the injected site.

My requirement is initially for internal use so I can do something server side but I was hoping it could be used more generally which is why I was looking for a client side solution. The other way to do what I want is using an browser extension or a collection of bookmarklets. Thanks very much for checking it out on. .