# How to handle the deprecation of Yahoo API?

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-maps

When I tried to call below Yahoo API it got responded with 503.I think it got depricated and is there any update API for this or else how can I resolve this issue.

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from xml where url="http://osom.cfa.vic.gov.au/public/osom/IN_COMING.rss&format=xml&callback=jQuery19103978128929438782_1596025470119&_=1596025470120
```

[image]

Does anyone know the successor of https://query.yahooapis.com/
Hope someone could help me to resolve this issue. Thanks  in advance

Comment: if that endpoint is depraceted, just stop using it...? and start using whatever that endpoint's successor is. however 503 does not imply permanent deprecation, it may be temporarily off or just cannot serve your request at time you tried for any other reason.

Comment: Do you know the successor of https://query.yahooapis.com

Comment: check out this [post from a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54046823/yql-query-service-replacement-now-that-yahoo-shut-it-down), it may help as much as the official [anouncement from Yahoo](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAHLKFlasZFIcpZCn-TRCJ0NdyrbB8eKBlS1xA8UMLjbujr_HflQlE6GqqRwPQEfV5AFAiwGFQN89MgPEscsfjpdjWKuFUIipE8UHWwSLew6yh5glLOpOueokVvMsGgL9edK4fSe4Q2aYuWcD7x5ldtN-whB5g6uSclwl2p9N6x4F)